# Where to call __syncthreads() function in CUDA

Tags: cuda, thread-synchronization

I have some bool variable , and my each threads must work with that , So I need to synchronise them it means I need to call `__syncthreads()` function in my program , but I don't know where to call it.

Comment: Please improve the question. If you don't know where to call __syncthreads then you like don't need to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__syncthreads()` function is  `__device__` function , so you must call it from your `__global__ kernel` or some other `__device__` function , additional `__syncthreads()` is a synchronization barrier primitive that only synchronizes threads in the same block.